# Visual Studio adding "MixedPlatform" solution configuration by itself

Tags: visual-studio

We have a large solution with only Debug/AnyCPU and Release/AnyCPU.   Occasionally Visual Studio (2010sp1) inserts of its own accord a "Mixed Platforms" configuration.   Since we have some projects (web) set to not build in our configuration, this messes with our build.  It also makes committing to source control a pain because a diff constantly shows the sln changed, and I have to reset it. 

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: No, you are not alone. [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207566/prevent-visual-studio-from-automatically-creating-mixed-platforms-solution-con)

Comment: Oh okay thanks :) Voting to close as dupe.

Comment: Seems to happen when you add a project, only way to fix is to delete after adding a new project