# App.Config stop creating

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

While we build project it will automatically create **App.Config** file...

But in case when we are not using this .Config file, so is there any way to stop create App.Config file.

Comment: Maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207566/prevent-visual-studio-from-automatically-creating-mixed-platforms-solution-con

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are not using it at all, just remove it from your project and it won't get created anymore.

Comment: I had deleted it from bin folder, but again next time while I build project, it re-create **App.Config**.

Comment: try to delete from your project files

Comment: I have deleted it and then it is not creating the config file with the same mane the executable has :(

Answer (score 9):

If the selected answer doesn't work for you, i.e. `App.Config` file still keeps getting created, then you likely have the Auto-generate binding redirects selected in your Project -> Properties.

[image]

In this case, you can uncheck and save this setting, and then remove the `app.config` file ans save the project.

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am creating a window service which has a name like "SomethingService", inside this, there is an "App.config" file. After compilation the output includes the following:

1. App.config
2. SomethingService.exe
3. SomethingService.exe.config

"SomethingService.exe.config" is actually a copy from "App.config" therefore there is no use for "App.config". Based on [How not to copy app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40293508/1257607):

[image: settings]

I have set these properties and the result is:

- No additional "App.config"
- "SomethingService.exe.config" which is a copy of "App.config"

just as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For those who a googling around, another possible reason that app.config is generated unintentionally may be a third party tool. For example, in our case, it was [Slow Cheetah](https://github.com/microsoft/slow-cheetah) extension which started creating app config with weird name on each build due to invalid setup (after we upgraded one of legacy projects). The fix was to provide correct configuration to this tool.